# Phussion Passenger fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

recently my app stacked and I tried to make some checks.
I run such command through console:
**passenger-config --detect-apache2**

Got this error.

```
Detecting configuration file location...
 --> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
Detecting error log file...
/home3/ecotec11/ruby/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/apache.rb:241:in `initialize': No such file or directory - /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (Errno::ENOENT)
        from /home3/ecotec11/ruby/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/apache.rb:241:in `open'
        from /home3/ecotec11/ruby/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/apache.rb:241:in `httpd_actual_error_log'
        from /home3/ecotec11/ruby/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info.rb:115:in `httpd_actual_error_log'
        from /home3/ecotec11/ruby/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/apache_detector.rb:148:in `block in detect_one'
        from /home3/ecotec11/ruby/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/apache_detector.rb:226:in `add_result'
        from /home3/ecotec11/ruby/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/apache_detector.rb:118:in `detect_one'
        from /home3/ecotec11/ruby/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/apache_detector.rb:112:in `block in detect_all'
        from /home3/ecotec11/ruby/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/apache_detector.rb:111:in `each'
        from /home3/ecotec11/ruby/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/apache_detector.rb:111:in `detect_all'
        from /home3/ecotec11/ruby/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/config/about_command.rb:140:in `run'
        from /home3/ecotec11/ruby/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/config/main.rb:60:in `run!'
        from /home3/ecotec11/ruby/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.37/bin/passenger-config:37:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home3/ecotec11/ruby/gems/bin/passenger-config:23:in `load'
        from /home3/ecotec11/ruby/gems/bin/passenger-config:23:in `<main>'
ecotec11@ecotechno.lv [~/rails_apps/darbs]#
```

Comment: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf is Apache config file. Do you have Apache installed and configured? Or do you have Apache config file located somewhere else?

Comment: @Octopus-Paul I did not install Apache by myself. It was already set up by my hosting company Justhost.com